# Linq returned results as condition to another linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var query_1 = from m in db.tableA
                        join n in db.tableB
                        on m.OwnerID equals n.OwnerID into tabA
                        from a in tabA
                        join o in db.tableC
                        on m.OwnerID equals o.OwnerID 
                        where m.UserID == userSessionID
                        && m.ActiveStatus == 1
                        select new { OwnerName = m.OwnerName };

var query_2 = from m in db.tableD
                        join n in db.tableE
                        on m.OwnerID equals n.OwnerID into tabX
                        from a in tabX
                        join o in db.tableF
                        on m.OwnerID equals o.OwnerID 
                        where {?????????????}
                        select new { ...... };
```

From the above code, query_1 will return me a list of elements retrieve from database. What I need is I only want the first item in the query_1 and using this element's column as a condition in my query_2. All this while i was using foreach to loop thru query_1 to get all the element but this time i only want the first item. Note that the list of query_1 may return me null and hence hardcode is not allow. Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after query_1;

```
var firstOwner = query_1.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

then in query_2, assuming m  (`db.tableD`) has an `OwnerName` property...

```
where m.OwnerName = firstOwner;
```

**Version 2**, If you need an `OwnerId` from query_1 :

change it to

```
select new { OwnerName = m.OwnerName, OwnerId = m.OwnerId };
```

than

```
var firstOwner = query_1.FirstOrDefault();
var firstOwnerId = firstOwner == null ? -1 : firstOwner.OwnerId;
```

and in query_2

```
where m.OwnerId = firstOwnerId;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, FirstOrDefault() method will throw an exception if my query_1 has more than 1 element?

Comment: @IsaacLem no. SingleOrDefault() would, FirstOrDefault() will just take... the first if there's something inside.

Comment: No - it won't - it will return null.  .Single() would throw an exception if your query returned more than 1, or 0 results.

Comment: @user2382536 FirstOrDefault() won't return null if there's more than 1 element. It will return the first.

Comment: If you order your results before selecting `FirstOrDefault`, I don't think it'll ever throw an exception for having more than one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use   `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first element from first query then you can use its value as needed.

You may also like to have a look [at](http://elegantcode.com/2008/09/23/i-love-firstordefault/) and [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it on a list then get the top most record as .First()?

```
        List<object> first = new List<object>();
        first = query_1.toList();
```

then on your query_2 put this:

```
        where m.OwnerId = first.First();
```

EDITED:

Or simply put this on your query_2:

```
        where m.OwnerId = query_1.First();
```